# Test if file is in \includeonly

Tags: conditionals, include

Is it possible to check if a file is listed inside `\includeonly{...}` ?

For example I would like to do something like this

```
\includeonly{file1,file2}
\if\isincluded file1       % \isincluded is a placeholder for the real test macro 
   \usepackage{apackage}
 \fi

 \begin{document}
 \include{file1}
 \include{file2}
 \end{document}
```

to avoid loading `apackage` when file1 is not included (because the package is expensive to load, like TikZ)

Comment: Hi mljrg. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following macro `\isincluded` uses the same test that `\include` uses
(code copied from there). If the file in the first argument will be included,
then the second argument is called, otherwise the third. Also the macro catches
the case, when `\includeonly` is not used and all files are included.

```
\documentclass{article}
\includeonly{file,file2}                     

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\isincluded}[1]{%
  \@tempswatrue
  \if@partsw   
    \@tempswafalse
    \edef\reserved@b{#1}%
    \@for\reserved@a:=\@partlist\do
      {\ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\@tempswatrue\fi}%
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\isincluded{file1}{%
  \usepackage{apackage}%
}{}

\begin{document}
\include{file1} 
\include{file2} 
\end{document}
```

If `\includeonly` is used the switch `\if@partsw` is true. Then the files of `\includeonly` are available in `\@partlist`.

### Extension: `\isincluded` with list of files

Use case: Resources (packages) must be loaded if some files are included. That means if either of the files in `\isincluded` will be included, then the test of
`\isincluded` evaluates to true (comma is "or" operator):

```
\documentclass{article}
\includeonly{file1,file3}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\isincluded}[1]{%
  \@tempswatrue
  \if@partsw
    \@tempswafalse
    \edef\isincluded@list{\zap@space#1 \@empty}% removes spaces in file list
    \@for\reserved@b:=\isincluded@list\do{%
      \@for\reserved@a:=\@partlist\do{%
        \ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\@tempswatrue\fi
      }%
    }%  
  \fi   
  \if@tempswa
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\isincluded{file2,file3}{%
  \usepackage{apackage}%
}{}

\begin{document}
\include{file1} 
\include{file2} 
\include{file3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: GREAT! I have just added to my .cls file! Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to make `\isincluded` receive a list of files, e.g., `\isincluded{file1,file3}`?

Comment: @Heiko: The question says "is it possible to check if a file is listed inside `\includeonly{...}`". I am rather confused by the use of `\@tempswatrue` in your solution. If `\includeonly` isn't called, `\@partsw` is false but your `\@tempswa` will be true.

Comment: @AhmedMusa If `\includeonly` is _not_ used, then this means _all_ files are included in LaTeX.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I am not even close to being a TeX/LaTeX guru, so is it easy to change your definition of `\isincluded` to work with a list of files, such that `\isincluded{file1,file3}{xxx}{yyy}` will include `xxx` if either file1 or file3 are included, and `yyy` otherwise? Thanks

Comment: @mljrg Already done 23 hours ago.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Oh, sorry, I did not refreshed my browser! Thanks again Heiko!

Answer (score 3):

The `\includeonly` files are saved i an `edef` called `\@partlist`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test1.tex}
  file 1
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test2.tex}
  file 2
\end{filecontents}
\includeonly{test2, test1}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
 \@partlist
\makeatother
\meaning\@partlist
\end{document}
```

Not too sure if this is of any help, but you can read the source2e routines.

Comment: I do not want to have all my content defined in only one file and then repeated in other files, as it seems from what I understand that filecontents does.

Comment: @mljrg the `filecontents` is just for making a MWE. In this case it creates the dummy files test1.tex and test2.tex

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own wrapper around `\includeonly` that tests for the filename

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\myincludeonly}[1]{%
  \def\do##1{\ifstrequal{##1}{file1}{\usepackage{tikz}}{}}
  \docsvlist{#1}
  \includeonly{#1}
}
\myincludeonly{file1,file2}

\begin{document}
\include{file1}
\include{file2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the issue I raised with Heiko's solution. In the following, **ifpdf** is input even though `\includeonly` is commented out.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\includeonly{file,file2} % commented

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\isincluded}[1]{%
  \@tempswatrue
  \if@partsw
    \@tempswafalse
    \edef\isincluded@list{\zap@space#1 \@empty}%
    \@for\reserved@b:=\isincluded@list\do{%
      \@for\reserved@a:=\@partlist\do{%
        \ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\@tempswatrue\fi
      }%
    }%
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\isincluded{file1}{%
  \usepackage{ifpdf}%
}{}

\begin{document}
\include{file1}
\include{file2}
\end{document}
```

My approach is

```
\documentclass{article}
% Comment out or retain the following:
\includeonly{file,file2}                     

\makeatletter
\newif\if@tempswb
\newcommand*{\ifincluded}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \@tempswbfalse
  \if@partsw
    \edef\@tempa{\zap@space#1 \@empty}%
    \@for\reserved@b:=\@tempa\do{%
      \@for\reserved@a:=\@partlist\do{%
        \ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\@tempswbtrue\fi
      }%
    }%  
  \fi   
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \if@tempswb
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\ifincluded{file1}{%
  \usepackage{ifpdf}%
}{}

\begin{document}
\include{file1} 
\include{file2} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: The inclusion of `ifpdf` in this case is indeed a feature. Without `\includeonly` LaTeX includes _all_ files `file` and `file2`, thus the test `\ifincluded{file1}` must evaluate to true.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: That is true, many thanks. But the letter of the question - "is it possible to check if a file is listed inside \includeonly{...}" - needed the clarification you have given latterly here.